# Assessing non-proportional hazards when proportional hazards assumption is violated

Tags: survival, cox-model, mortality

**Could you help me to proceed with a request by a reviewer?**

I have a Cox model like this

time_1year | status ~ p1 + p2 + p3 + p4

I was not able to perform Cox regression at 2 year as the proportional hazard assumption was violated.

**Reviewer asked us to do the following:**

Conduct an analysis that includes time x covariate interactions to address non-proportional hazards, so that mortality risk at 2 year can be assessed.

**What and how should I do it? I can use R and SPSS.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you jump to time*covariate interactions, consider other ways of handling violation of proportional hazards (PH). [This page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/269186/28500) contains several recommendations, including using a log-normal model that wouldn't require PH. If any of your predictors are continuous, a [transformation might help](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/379416/28500).

Failing those, the [time-dependent vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/vignettes/timedep.pdf) for the R [`survival` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=survival) shows ways to proceed. One simple approach that sometimes works is to split the time scale in a way that PH is met within each of the time epochs. A full interaction of a covariate with an arbitrary continuous function of time is provided by the `tt()` functionality of that package, but be careful to follow the instructions carefully lest you fall into a [very common error](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/384074/28500).